# Flutter: cutting a row in "half"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've been toying with lists in flutter, and everything is fine. I'm starting to understand the logic of the whole thing.

Now I wanted to do a simple layout like that :
[image: layout example]

My problem is that I can't find a way to make the first row. I tried to tell Row to let its two children take half and no less no more, but I didn't really find a way. (The inside thing will eventually be buttons.)I tried several things to no avail. Here is the layout I started from :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: buttonPaddingTop,
                  left: buttonPaddingSide,
                  right: buttonPaddingSide),
              child: ButtonTheme(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: const Text('LARGE TEXT',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: buttonFontSize)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: buttonPaddingTop,
                  left: buttonPaddingSide,
                  right: buttonPaddingSide),
              child: ButtonTheme(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: const Text('LARGE TEXT',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: buttonFontSize)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    ),
  );
}
```

Should I continue trying like this, or should I try another object than Row to arrange the layout ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) takes as much space as available in this case horizontally. That means if you would use 2 `Expanded` widgets inside your `Row`, the space will be divided by half.

Try this:

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Text('first half'),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text('second half'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Text('first half'),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text('second half'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Text('full width'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Make sure you read more about Flutter widgets, for example watch this video (and other ones in this series):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo

Comment: Thanks for the link, based on what I used Expanded it should work, I'll try that.

Comment: @moo I added a more complete answer, so 2 rows of half in size and the third full width.

Comment: worst thing is that I used expanded in another context while doing a list row with something on the beginning, something in the ending, and an Expanded in between to take all the space and to be able to use textoverflow ^^

Comment: @moo It's ok, it happens to everyone :)